# catch spark return code in Unix shell script

Tags: bash, scala, unix, apache-spark

how to catch return code of a spark-submit job , I wrote a shell script to pass arguments and run spark submit with my spark class, I used below code to catch the return code but its not working.Run spark is a function in my shell script which runs spark submit with spark class and arguments.

```html
RunSpark

ret_code=$?
if [[ ${ret_code} != 0 ]]; then
   exit ${ret_code} "Issue while executing spark class ${spark_class}"
fi

exit 0 echo "Script ran ok !"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the wrong comparison operator `-ne`, echo and exit are separate commands, they can't be at the same line. Also you should call echo before exit, otherwise the script won't print anything. This should work:

```
# generating random numbers from 0 to 3, just for testing purposes                                                                                                       
ret_code=$(( ( RANDOM % 4 )  ))

if [[ ${ret_code} -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Issue while executing spark class ${spark_class}"
    exit ${ret_code}
fi

echo "Script ran ok !"
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the string comparison operator != rather than then numeric -ne

it should be

```
if [[ ${ret_code} -ne 0 ]]; then
```